# Optimizing Array Inverting Transform

Tags: javascript, php, arrays, algorithm

I have data similar to the following:

List of students and the school they attend

```
[
    {
        "uid": 100,
        "name": "Adam",
        "school": {
            "id": 1,
            "name": "NYHS"
        }
    },
    {
        "uid": 101,
        "name": "Bob",
        "school": {
            "id": 2,
            "name": "PAHS"
        }
    },
    {
        "uid": 102,
        "name": "Charles",
        "school": {
            "id": 1,
            "name": "NYHS"
        }
    },
    {
        "uid": 103,
        "name": "David",
        "school": {
            "id": 3,
            "name": "MMDS"
        }
    }
]
```

And I want to transform it to a list of schools with the students that attend it.

```
[
    {
        "id": 1,
        "name": "NYHS",
        "students": [
            {
                "uid": 100,
                "name": "Adam"
            },
            {
                "uid": 102,
                "name": "Charles"
            },
        ]
    },
        "id": 2,
        "name": "NYHS",
        "students": [
            {
                "uid": 101,
                "name": "Bob"
            }
        ]
    },
        "id": 3,
        "name": "MMDS",
        "students": [
            {
                "uid": 103,
                "name": "David"
            }
        ]
    },
]
```

I have a working version of it, but it's long and probably not performant. Is there a shorter/faster way to do it?

Doesn't really matter what language.

Tried used map/reduce and I got the unique schools, but not sure how to merge the students into it.

```
$schools = array_reduce(
    array_map(function ($a) {
        return $a['school'];
    }, $students), 
    function ($s, $i) {
        if (count(array_filter($s, function ($j) use ($i) {
            return $j['id'] == $i['id'];
        })) == 0) {
            array_push($s, $i);
        }
        return $s;
    }, 
    array()
);
```

Comment: I hope you have use reduce method to group data

Comment: JavaScript or PHP?

Comment: @nnnnnn doesn't matter. either works

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42019461/mapping-json-data-reverse!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd probably minimise looping by using a call to `.reduce()` to create an object with a property for each school, followed by mapping that object to the final output array:

```js
var input = [ // whitespace compressed to avoid vertical scrolling
    { "uid": 100, "name": "Adam", "school": { "id": 1, "name": "NYHS" } },
    { "uid": 101, "name": "Bob", "school": { "id": 2, "name": "PAHS" } },
    { "uid": 102, "name": "Charles", "school": { "id": 1, "name": "NYHS" } },
    { "uid": 103, "name": "David", "school": { "id": 3, "name": "MMDS" } }
]

var schoolObj = input.reduce(function(p,c) {
  if (!(c.school.id in p))
    p[c.school.id] = { id: c.school.id, name: c.school.name, students: [] }
  p[c.school.id].students.push({ uid: c.uid, name: c.name })
  return p
}, {})

var schoolArr = Object.keys(schoolObj).map(function(s) { return schoolObj[s] })

console.log(schoolArr)
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's one way to do it:

```
function myTransform(input) {

  // Store the output of the transform as an object
  // Here I assume that the school id is unique
  var output = {};

  input.forEach((e) => {

    if (!output[e.school.id]) {

      // If the school id doesn't exist in the output then generate it, and put the school & student data into it
      output[e.school.id] = {
        id: e.school.id,
        name: e.school.name,
        students: [{
          uid: e.uid,
          name: e.name
        }]
      };
    } else {

      // If the school id exists in the output, then push the student data into it
      output[e.school.id].students.push({
        uid: e.uid,
        name: e.name
      });
    }
  });

  // Convert the output into an array
  return Object.keys(output).map((e) => output[e]);
}
```

I used an object to store the output in order to avoid using nested loops (I'm not sure if that's the best way to do it though). Finally, I convert the object to an array.

Answer (score 1):

```js
var arr = [{"uid":100,"name":"Adam","school":{"id":1,"name":"NYHS"}},{"uid":101,"name":"Bob","school":{"id":2,"name":"PAHS"}},{"uid":102,"name":"Charles","school":{"id":1,"name":"NYHS"}},{"uid":103,"name":"David","school":{"id":3,"name":"MMDS"}}];

var result = Object.values(                                                 // get the values of the hash object
    arr.reduce(function(hash, o) {
        var id = o.school.id;                                               // get the school id
        hash[id] = hash[id] || {id: id, name: o.school.name, students: []}; // check if the school is already in the hash object, if not create add it
        hash[id].students.push({id: o.id, name: o.name});                   // add this student to its students array
        return hash;
    }, {})
);

console.log(result);
```

Comment: `Object.values()` is sure going to come in handy, once it's stable and supported in all current browsers. (I guess there's always a polyfill.)

Answer (score 1):

Here's a PHP version that retains all the other fields you might have.

```
$output = array_reduce($input, function($result, $item) {
    $id = $item["school"]["id"];
    if (!isset($result[$id])) {
        $result[$id] = array_merge($item["school"], ["students" => []]);
    }
    $result[$id]["students"][] = array_diff_key($item, ["school" => null]);
    return $result;
}, []);
```

[Try it online](https://3v4l.org/FjN2r).